# Div cannot be center aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

#### Problem

When I try to use the code (**see below**), the div is only centered when I use `width: 100px;`.

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

[image: Screenshot from the website]

Since I want to assign a much longer width to the text and set the width to `500px`, the div is no longer centered.

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

#### Problem #2

[image]

The svg isn't centered

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="ud-single-feature wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".25s" >
        <div class="ud-feature-icon" >
            <i class="lni lni-layers"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ud-feature-content" style="position:absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center;">

            <h3 class="ud-feature-title" style="text-align: center;">test</h3>
            <p class="ud-feature-desc" style="text-align: center;">
                test
            </p>
            <!--                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ud-feature-link">
                                        Learn More
                                    </a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: <div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

Comment: Please avoid posting code in comments. Also, that is not a [mre].

Comment: How should the desired output look like?

Comment: I have now updated the problem, see the updated question.

Comment: This is not full code, how do I obtain the SVG - there must be some links, stylesheets. As I said earlier, please post a [mre].

Comment: The problem is now solved, the problem was that I had to change the class.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question does not define your desired goal, using margin-left or right will not justify the centre point of the page. Instead, consider using `position: fixed` in order to centre exactly in the page.

This should also mean you can set the dimensions of the div as you like.

```
<div style="background: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">Div should be properly centred in page.</div>
```

Comment: I have now updated the problem, see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div as a child of another div like so :

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have now updated the problem, see the updated question.

Comment: @etoby. Can you please provide your full html code and not just the div ? that will be easier to make an answer for.

Comment: The problem is now solved, the problem was that I had to change the class.

Comment: @etoby. ok no problem.